# Importing data from .csv using mongoimprt

Tags: node.js, mongodb, shell-exec, mongoimport, csv-import

I am trying to import 7 million records from a CSV file into a collection using mongoimport . This collection already have around 8 million records. I want to check if there are any duplicate emails while importing the records from the file. To achieve this, I am using --mode upsert --upsertFields email. I am using NodeJS for this purpose and executing command using shell-exec package. While running the command I gets an error message which I am unable to understand. I would really appreciate if anyone could help me out. Below is the error message which I am getting.

> 2022-10-20T19:39:52.847+0100\tconnected to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/\n2022-10-20T19:39:55.849+0100\t[…] notitia.usb2bs\t1.09MB/1.22GB (0.1%)\n2022-10-20T19:39:58.849+0100\t[…] notitia.usb2bs\t1.09MB/1.22GB (0.1%)\n2022-10-20T19:40:01.240+0100\t[…] notitia.usb2bs\t1.09MB/1.22GB (0.1%)\n2022-10-20T19:40:01.240+0100\tFailed: (InterruptedAtShutdown) interrupted at shutdown\n2022-10-20T19:40:01.240+0100\t0 document(s) imported successfully. 0 document(s) failed to import.\n

Comment: Is the database shutting down while attempting to run this import? What does the `mongod` log file say?

Comment: failed to delete .sock file. I believe using --mode with upsert is takes such a long time that connecting get closed. I might be wrong I am not sure.

Comment: Failed to delete that file is generally an indication that the database (MongoDB) process is failing to start altogether. I don't think your import process would have reported the "connected to" message if that were the case